# MySQL UPDATE performance with or without WHERE IS NULL

Tags: mysql, performance

Lets say I have 300 million users in my mysql database (`innodb`). Some of them have `username` set, while some of them don't (username is null), and lets say 60% of them are not null (have actual varchar value).

If I wanted to set all 300 million users' usernames to null, would

`UPDATE users SET username = null WHERE username IS NOT NULL`

perform better than

`UPDATE users SET username = null` - without a WHERE clause, just blanket null them all?

I know that WHERE always performs faster when setting actual values, but somehow null fields made me think about this.

Comment: If you have index for username, `WHERE` would be better otherwise should perform the same because need to do a full scan. Assign null or a value doesn't make any difference on this case.

Comment: Read up on explain query for self evaluation of the query performance.

Comment: check out this fiddle for some better understanding: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=De4TPIMgUO

Comment: @manu - `EXPLAIN` won't tell you about the huge overhead of building a undo/redo log.

Answer (score 1):

Both will take terrrrribly long.  I suggest you do it in 'chunks' as described in my blog here:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Here is another solution:

```
ALTER TABLE t DROP COLUMN c;
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN c VARCHAR(...) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Each `ALTER` will copy the table over once *without* writing to the ROLLBACK log (etc), thereby being significantly faster.  (I doubt if you can combine the two into a single statement.)

But first, let's back up and discuss *why* you need to do this unusual task.  It is likely to indicate a poor schema design.  And rethinking the design *may* be a better approach.

Comment: Purely academical. Just a thing that got me wondering. Interesting approach with copying the columns though, thinking outside the box :)